# Is there a library to connect my Terminal using Robot Frmaework?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pentaho-data-integration, robotframework-ide

I want to run jobs in terminal connecting SSH tunnels. Is there any way that I can do it?

> ```
> I should connect to Terminal
> Access SSH tunnels
> Access pentaho. sudo us - pentaho
> Run my jobs
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SSHLibrary - https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary & http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I actually trying to run this command:
Run Process       python   ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p 10.10.10.10' 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
Am getting below error:
"Keyword argument 'ssh -o ProxyCommand' is not supported by this keyword"